# movie15 package and playing time information in a pdf-embeded video

Tags: movie15

I am working with the beamer class and using the movie15 package to embed videos into a pdf document.

I notice that when I includde mp4-format videos the embedded player does not include run time information (i.e., a counter/timer like you typically would have on a DVD player which shows you where you are within a given video with respect to time). When I embed a wmv-format video file, this player does include time information in the space above the player controls and below the video images. I could just reformat my mp4 clips into wmv, but I prefer the look of the player as it appears in the mp4 format.

Is there a way of getting the mp4-format player to include a timer which shows the passage of time while the video is running? I don't really care whether the time information were to appear outside the video images as part of the player or, on the other hand, superimposed upon the actual video frames.

I consulted Alexander Grahn's movie15 documentation to no avail.

Here are the specifics of my tex document (MiKTeX 2.8, TeXnicCenter):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{movie15}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\title[\textit{Teaching ...}]{Ballrooms and Buses ...}
\author[...]{...}
\institute{...}
\date{July 8, 2011}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.jpg}{.bmp}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[]{breakurl}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

%lots of sections and frames, among these:

\section{Mink-Wearing ...}

\begin{frame}{...}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[toolbar,autoclose,poster,text={\includegraphics[width=9.1cm, height=4.8cm]{HMspeech.png}}]{9.1cm}{4.8cm}{HMspeech.mp4}

\caption{... Acceptance Speech}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

%more sections and frames leading up to:

\section[Dance]{Dance: ...}

\begin{frame}{... and Dance}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[toolbar,autoclose,poster]{5.04cm}{4.32cm}{rumba.wmv}

\vspace{20pt}

\caption{... Rumba (2003)}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

%more sections and frames

\end{document}
```

Should anyone have taken time to read my question: Thank you!

Comment: How is this off topic? movie15 is a latex package.